Shading on mesh has tons of artifacts in both flat and smooth shading


One part of this mesh is having immense artifacting in its shading between both smooth shading and flat shading modes.
The issue only started after the one part of the mesh was scaled. Scaling it back does not have any effect. Boolean operations have not been used.
The mesh is all fully connected, there are no duplicate faces, there are no modifiers, normals have been recalculated countless times, but the artifacts remain regardless. No other areas on this mesh have these artifacting issues. When duplicating, the duplicated faces have the same issue.
Blender ver. 4.1, Windows 10 Home 19045, AMD Radeon RX 6750 XT

Could you please add the file? That would make it easier for us to track down the problem. See blend-exchange.com to upload your blend file (if you want to).

check whether all vertices are connected/double. Check face orientation.

It's probably due to bad split normals (the normals that determine the shading), to fix that go into the Data panel > Geometry and click on the Clear Custom Split Normals Data:

